# Find Im $\varphi$, Ker $\varphi$ and representation matrix of $\varphi$

Tags: linear-transformations

> Suppose $V=V_1 \oplus V_2$, and $\varphi$ is a linear transformation on $V$ satisfying
>   $$\varphi(v_1+v_2)=v_1$$
>   where $v_i\in V_i$ for $i=1,2$. Show that $\varphi=\varphi^{2}$, and find Im $\varphi$ and Ker $\varphi$. If $V_1$ and $V_2$ have basis of $\{e_1, \cdots, e_r\}$ and $\{e_{r+1}, \cdots, e_n\}$, respectively, find the representation matrix of $\varphi$ on $V$.

I have proved the first statement, how do I solve the following subquestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let's do a concrete case. We can write $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$. Then $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $\varphi(x,y)=x$. Indeed, $\varphi^2=\varphi$. Notice that every $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ is hit by $\varphi$, because for any $y\in \mathbb{R}$, $(x_0,y)\mapsto x_0$. So, $\operatorname{im}(\varphi)=\mathbb{R}.$ Next, the kernel of $\varphi$ is $\varphi^{-1}(0)=\{(x,0): x\in \mathbb{R}\}$. That is the first direct summand above and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Finally, to calculate the matrix representation, we  use as a basis for $\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$ the vectors $(1,0)=e_1$ and $(0,1)=e_2$. Then $\varphi(e_1)=1$ and $\varphi(e_2)=0$. So, the matrix is 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1&0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Try to generalize this argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sum is direct, the image is $V_1$ and the kernel is $V_2$. The representation matrix is composed of the unit matrix for $V_1$ and the zero matrix for $V_2$.
Generally, if you take a basis $\{b_1,\ldots, b_k\}$ of $V$, then the transformation matrix is given by $A=(a_{ij})$ where $\phi(b_j) = \sum_{i} a_{ij}b_i$, i.e., the $j$th column of $A$ is given by 
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 
\ldots & a_{ij} & \ldots\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
\ldots & a_{kj}& \vdots 
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Do you have detailed solution? I don't understand how representation matrix is derived from.